# How to suppress a style sheet or script from another module?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9, orchardcms-1.10

Is there a recommended way to suppress style sheets or scripts that are defined in the ResourceManifest of, and required by, another module?

I use a lot of reusable features that I carry over between Orchard projects. Each feature includes its own style sheet and/or script. For performance reasons, I want to bundle all of them before deploying a website. I need to prevent all the individual styles and scripts from loading since my single bundled file already contains all of them. Can I achieve this through my ResourceManifest?

Comment: Quick thought: #1 Use `[OrchardSurpressDependency()]` attribute (carefully!).
#2 Specify _all_ the modules you want to override as dependency. This way your module get's the highest priority and `Require` calls should redirect to your module.

3# Look at the resource pipeline. I'm pretty sure there's a priority mechanism buried in there, but I don't remember exactly how it works right now.

Comment: @Xceno I can specify a resource with the same name in my module and it takes my version of the resource. If I define a resource without setting an Url or Cdn, nothing is loaded. This is pretty much what I wanted, except I get a bunch of empty <link> and <script> tags in my source. If I can find a way to remove them from the flow entirely instead of just making them empty, it'll be perfect.